# Correlation cutoff in caret train preProcess

Tags: r, correlation, r-caret, preprocessor

I'm building a C5.0 model with the caret package in r.

```
control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                    number = 10, 
                    repeats = 3, 
                    classProbs = TRUE, 
                    sampling = 'smote',
                    returnResamp="all",
                    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

grid <- expand.grid(.winnow = c(FALSE, TRUE), 
                 .trials = c(1, 5,10,15,20,25,30,40,45,50), 
                 .model= c("tree"),
                 .splits=c(2,5,10,15,20,25,50))

c5_model <- train(label ~ .,
              data = train,
              trControl = control, 
              method = c5info,
              tuneGrid = grid, 
              preProcess = c("center", "scale", "nzv","corr"),
              verbose = FALSE)
```

Is it possible to pass a custom cutoff point to the preProcess function for the correlation - say 0.75 or whatever point I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the pre process options in `trainControl`:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench) #for the data
data(Sonar)

ctrl <-trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                    number = 10, 
                    repeats = 3, 
                    classProbs = TRUE, 
                    sampling = 'smote',
                    returnResamp="all",
                    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                    preProcOptions = list(cutoff = 0.75)) # all go in this list
```

some ranger model:

```
grid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(2,5,10),
                    .min.node.size = 2,
                    .splitrule = "gini")

fit_model <- train(Class ~ .,
                  data = Sonar,
                  trControl = ctrl, 
                  metric = "ROC",
                  method = "ranger",
                  tuneGrid = grid,
                  preProcess = c("center", "scale", "nzv","corr"),
                  verbose = FALSE)

fit_model$preProcess
#output
Created from 679 samples and 60 variables

Pre-processing:
  - centered (26)
  - ignored (0)
  - removed (34)
  - scaled (26)
```

using a different cutoff:

```
ctrl2 <-trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                    number = 10, 
                    repeats = 3, 
                    classProbs = TRUE, 
                    sampling = 'smote',
                    returnResamp="all",
                    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                    preProcOptions = list(cutoff = 0.6))

fit_model2 <- train(Class ~ .,
                   data = Sonar,
                   trControl = ctrl2, 
                   metric = "ROC",
                   method = "ranger",
                   tuneGrid = grid,
                   preProcess = c("center", "scale", "nzv","corr"),
                   verbose = FALSE)

fit_model2$preProcess
#output
Created from 679 samples and 60 variables

Pre-processing:
  - centered (23)
  - ignored (0)
  - removed (37)
  - scaled (23)
```

more columns are removed

and when we use `preProcOptions = list(cutoff = 0.95))`

```
fit_model3$preProcess
#output
Created from 679 samples and 60 variables

Pre-processing:
  - centered (55)
  - ignored (0)
  - removed (5)
  - scaled (55)
```

Looks like it works.

Likewise you can pass any other pre process options:

```
?caret::preProcess
```

to check all of them

Comment: Initial problem solved but when the model ran, it gave an error "Error in findCorrelation_fast(x = x, cutoff = cutoff, verbose = verbose) : The correlation matrix has some missing values." 
How do I instruct the function to do a pairwise complete correlation?

Comment: Do you have some `NA` in the data? If yes try to remove them or to impute them. Does the problem still occur?

Comment: Will passing na.action = na.pass into train cut it?

Comment: I'm sure though that there's no NA in the data... strange?

Comment: Its really hard to troubleshoot such behavior without data. What I would do is try to run just `preProcess` with `"corr"` on the data and see if it works (outside `train`) - if not I would try to run the R function `cor` - if still not working I would try to find out why - if  could not  I would post another question here with a subset of data which can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suspect it's because of near zero variance predictors in the data, is there any way I can remove the zero variance predictors **before** evaluating the correlation matrix?

Comment: Unable to post data for privacy reasons.

Comment: caret has an inbuilt function for that [`nearZeroVar`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/nearZeroVar). Run it on the train data prior using `train`.

Comment: To give more clarity on my suspicion, yes "corr" runs on the data after I'd done a "preProcess(data, method = c("nzv", "center", "scale"), cutoff = 0.75)" on the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173136/discussion-between-user1783739-and-missuse).